# I'm having problems to copy a row from one tab on the spreadsheet and copy in another one

Tags: google-apps-script, spreadsheet

I'm a beginner and need help with a Google Spreadsheet script.

When I click on the check box on the MAIN tab, I want to copy the line (column A, B and C) and paste it into the COMPLETED tab, and after that, delete the data from the line I clicked on the MAIN tab (only in column B and C) and deselect the check box on the MAIN tab.

Can someone help me?

Here's a [link](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1___-2E0sPUIMAzHyRxLuu-KWhV70zrKZxt6amF2l1cs/edit?usp=sharing) of my shared spreadsheet

Here the script:

```
function onEdit(event) {
  // assumes source data in sheet named main
  // target sheet of move to named Completed
  // getColumn with check-boxes is currently set to column 4 or D
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var s = ss.getActiveSheet();
  var r = s.getActiveRange();

  if(s.getName() == "main" && r.getColumn() == 4 && r.getValue() == true) {
    var row = r.getRow();
    var numColumns = s.getLastColumn();
    var targetSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Completed");
    var target = targetSheet.getRange(targetSheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1);
    s.getRange(row, 1, 1, numColumns).moveTo(target);
    s.deleteRow(row);
  } else if(s.getName() == "Completed" && r.getColumn() == 4 && r.getValue() == false) {
    var row = r.getRow();
    var numColumns = s.getLastColumn();
    var targetSheet = ss.getSheetByName("main");
    var target = targetSheet.getRange(targetSheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1);
    s.getRange(row, 1, 1, numColumns).moveTo(target);
    s.deleteRow(row);
  }
}
```

Comment: When I saw your shared Spreadsheet, the "Completed" sheet has column "D". But in your question, you say you want to copy only the columns A, B and C from "main" to "Completed", and I cannot understand about the column "D" in "Completed". And about `delete the data from the line I clicked on the MAIN tab (only in column B and C) and deselect the check box on the MAIN tab.`, in this case, the columns "B" and "C" are empty. Under this condition, when the checkbox is checked, you want to copy the row including the empty values? At that time, where does the checkbox in "Completed" sheet come from?

Comment: And, when I saw your "Completed" sheet, I found `Un-check a box to move it back to “main” sheet and delete it from this sheet.`. You want to append the row and delete whole row? Unfortunately, I cannot understand about what you want to do. I apologize for my poor English skill. Can I ask you about the detail of your current issue and your goal?

Comment: @Tanaike: The main sheet holds 3 sets for review.  When a user checks the box in column D, delete the row from the main sheet and add the row to the Completed sheet, leaving the box checked.  If the user unchecks the box in column D of the Completed sheet, delete the row from the Completed sheet and add the row to the main sheet, leaving the box unchecked.

Comment: Thank you for your support. In the case of situation of your comment, I think that OP's script has already achieved it. So, when I could find the OP's issue, I would like to think of the solution.